# Moderncv enumerate in cvitem: Bug?

Tags: enumerate, moderncv

I wanted to know if people can reproduce my problem with the misaligned enumeration and if yes why is it like this?

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{}{}

\begin{document}
\cvitem{Bar}{
\begin{itemize}
\item First test
\end{itemize}
}
\cvitem{Foo}{
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Second test
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Misalignment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `enumerate` adds a white space before starting the enumerated list, `itemize` does it not.  That is the reason for the different layout you get.

But there is a workaround:

```
%   \vspace{-7.5pt}%
    \vspace{-0.55\baselineskip}%
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Second test
      \item Second line
    \end{enumerate}
```

I did not search where exactly that space comes from, but in your case both values `-7.5pt` and `-0.55\baselineskip` did shift up the enumerated list to the groundline of the title `Foo` of your `\cvitem` ...

See the following complete code

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{Joe}{Doe}


\begin{document}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}

\cvitem{Bar}{%
  \begin{itemize}
    \item First test
    \item Second line
  \end{itemize}
}
\cvitem{Foo}{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Second test
    \item Second line
  \end{enumerate}
}

\cvitem{Foo}{% <======================================================
%   \vspace{-7.5pt}%
    \vspace{-0.55\baselineskip}%
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Second test
      \item Second line
    \end{enumerate}
}

\cvitem{Test}{Test}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: resulting list]

Please note that I did not test this with other fonts or fontsizes, so it could be that you have to change the used value `-7.5pt` or `-0.55\baselineskip` for your needs ...

Comment: Do you know why enumerate adds an additional vertical space before its start if it is at the beginning of a new paragraph? This behavior is different in the document class `moderncv` compared to e.g. `article` -- where I see the expected equal spacing behavior.

Comment: @strpeter no, I didn't look for that in the code of class `moderncv`, sorry. I do not know where it comes from ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is expected behaviour since "enumerate" is unexpected, for entries in that CV.

[image]
Alignment is generally well set to hold the vertical line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{}{}

\begin{document}
\cvitem{Foo}{
\begin{itemize} % bullet POINTed items
\item First bullet point
\item Second bullet point
\item Third bullet point
\end{itemize}
}
\cvitem{Bar}{ % an eNUMerated list
\begin{enumerate}
 \item First Line
 \item Second Line
 \item Third Line
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{document}
```

The behaviour for heading items, does vary for the two cases, so if the cv item is multi-line prefix it will wrap above / below the first enumerated item or if a heading will be applied above the enumerated list.  Otherwise the two behave exactly the same if wrapped around the first item.

[image]